# Will image from an inline background-image style be loaded if the element is hidden?

Tags: css

I have background images which are uploaded as content via my CMS and as such have to be rendered inline:

```
<div class="image" style="background-image: user-upload.jpg"></div>
```

I don't need to show these image at smaller screen widths. How can I also make sure the image isnt loaded needlessly to keep the page size down?

This seems to be a good resource but it doenst deal with inline styles:

https://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

```
@media (max-width: 600px {
    .image {
      display: none;
    }

    .image {
      background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it will be loaded

Comment: Don't put your css inline then, when css is inline it is usually the last piece of code interpreted so it overrides what you put in a file (inluding media queries in most cases)

Comment: @RDardelet The image needs to be content so this is a limitation of the CMS im afraid.

Comment: Well there is your problem i think, you either need to find a way to get your image out of the inline CSS or pray for a miracle

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would have the background-image declaration not inline styled - not sure if in your use case this is possible.

But if you could get it out then you could leave your `.image` class to handle whatever CSS it does now and then use jQuery to add or remove an additional class that would only control the background-image of the div.

```
var width = $(window).width();   
if (width <= 300 or whatever width you want) {                          
    $(".image").removeClass('yourclassforaBGimg');          
}
else {
    $(".image").addClass('yourclassforaBGimg'); 
}
```

If this is run in the header of the page then the class containing the image will have been removed from the page altogether before the browser begins rendering it and it won't be loaded at all.

Comment: Yeah from what we said in the comments, he is stuck with inline css
and your solution wouldn't work since the image element will need to be loaded by the browser before the script is executed, otherwise it will return a reference error.

Comment: Ahh hadn't seen that the OP said he was forced to leave it inline!